# Integration by parts with a gradient operator

Tags: integration, derivatives, vector-analysis

I know that integration of parts can be used on a single integral:
$$\int \frac{df}{dx} g   \,dx = fg - \int f\frac{dg}{dx}  \,dx$$

For a triple integral with a gradient operator, is the following operation legitimate?
$$\iiint_V \nabla(f)g \,dV \,=?\, fg - \iiint_V f\nabla(g) \,dV$$ 
If not, how would one simplify the expression on the left? Please explain.

Comment: For you, what is the meaning of integrate a thing like $(\nabla f)g$?

Comment: This would be the divergence theorem. The boundary term in the middle should be a surface integral. Except its only defined if the triple integral argument is a scalar function, which this is not.

Comment: @ninadmunshi Your comment is simply incorrect.  See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_V \nabla(f)\,g\,dV&=\int_V \left( \nabla(fg) -f\nabla(g)\right)\,dV\\\\
&=\oint_S fg \hat n\,dS- \int_V f \nabla(g) \,dV
\end{align}$$

where $S$ is the boundary of $V$ and $\hat n$ is the outward unit normal of $S$.